# Setting th:value with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, spring, thymeleaf

How can I use selected option from selection in other field? I have tried using javascript function but I don't know how to set th:value.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectSprint(selected) {
            var index = selected.selectedIndex;
            var selectedSprint = selected.option[index].value;
            var setInput = document.getElementById("setInput");
            setInput.value = selectedSprint;
        }
    </script>

<select th:field="*{id}" onchange="selectSprint(this);">
    <option th:each="entry : ${list}" th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value.name}">
    </option>
</select> 

<input type="text" id="setInput" th:value=""></input>
```

Or is there any other method in thymeleaf to choose and send more than one value? (I want to send `${entry.key}` and `${entry.value.sprintDuration}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the view language here is XHTML, not HTML

Usually XHTML based frameworks like ASP.NET or JSF in Java use these `th:value` attributes to set value on the **server side**

Please check that in final HTML (F12) you can still see `th:value` attribute for your `<input>`, because I think you will not see it

**UPD**

Didnt see that you're using thymeleaf. Well, in this case I suggest you to create a **form** to send you data to the server

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#creating-a-form

Because frameworks like thymeleaf usualy stores state on server which means you update server first - and then your UI gets updated

Comment: Thanks, I'm using form but I'm having some problems with it because when I have Object i Object i can't set value of the inner object with thymeleaf but I founded a diffrent solution so I make totally different Object with only variables I'm getting from the scope.